# Does ARCore supports SLAM and AreaLearning?

Tags: android, arcore, tango, slam

I'm trying to achieve Indoor Navigation system in shopping mall or an office ? Is that possible using existing ARCore ?

Comment: Related - see section on Mapping: https://medium.com/6d-ai/how-is-arcore-better-than-arkit-5223e6b3e79d and tying it in with the 'Cloud Anchors' support: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/cloud-anchors/cloud-anchors-overview-android but the anchors are only good for 24 hours. Follow up article: https://medium.com/6d-ai/dawn-of-the-ar-cloud-1b31eb4b52ac

Comment: According to ARCore's documentation, its motion tracking is based on "[concurrent odometry and mapping](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/concepts)," which is similar to SLAM.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, looks like you want to achieve something similar https://community.arm.com/graphics/b/blog/posts/indoor-real-time-navigation-with-slam-on-your-mobile

Comment: Welcome to SO. Posting link-only-answers is discouraged. It's better to give a gist of the solution along with the link